# What are the practical differences between SELinux targeted mode and a capability based OS?

Tags: mandatory-access-control, capabilities, selinux

I recently asked a [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9180/can-hips-software-practically-be-considered-a-form-of-mac) about the differences between capabilities and mandatory access controls.

Among the answers I got the point was made that systems like SE Linux in targeted mode are not a typical MAC system, as the concern is not about restricting information flow.

Then, in a framework like SE Linux targeted mode where the focus would seem to be on minimizing harm in the event of unauthorized access, how different is this in practice from a capability based system?

Note, I am only asking about the practical different, not the theoretical differences. Are different attacks possible on SELinux in targeted mode than on a capability based operating system? Can they both prevent access to the same granular level? Etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a lot of the problem with capability-based systems and our understanding of them is that there are few in the wild. However, you're in luck - FreeBSD have just added [capsicum](http://www.lightbluetouchpaper.org/2012/01/30/freebsd-9-0-ships-with-experimental-capsicum-support/) support to their 9.0 release. Capsicum is a research project to implement a [lightweight practical set of capabilities][1]. This work involved people at the Google Security Research team and includes an experimental chrome browser build designed to use the system.

What might be most of interest to you are the list of features:

> - capabilities - refined file descriptors with fine-grained rights

Practically, will operate *like* SELinux, with obvious administration differences. Has analogies to type labels.

> - process descriptors - capability-centric process ID replacement

Has analogies to SELinux domains. From a user perspective, may appear to be no different.

Now, in the next set of features you see why capabilities aren't yet in common usage:

> - anonymous shared memory objects - an extension to the POSIX shared memory API to support anonymous swap objects associated with file descriptors (capabilities)
> - rtld-elf-cap - modified ELF run-time linker to construct sandboxed applications
> - libcapsicum - library to create and use capabilities and sandboxed components

Whereas SELinux requires kernel support and a policy and is ok to go from there, configuration problems aside, practically implementing capabilities requires a modified approach to the APIs available and subsequent preparation of applications to access them.

Now specifically to your questions:

> Can they both prevent access to the same granular level?

Roughly comparable, yes. SELinux can, for example, describe an application domain and give it access to a certain folder for reads only. Capability based systems would, when initialising the process, simply not hand it a capability to write to that path, or refuse such requests subsequently. It's the how they're implemented that varies.

> Are different attacks possible on SELinux in targeted mode than on a capability based operating system?

Honestly, it's quite hard to say. I don't know of any mass-deployed capability based operating system that's attracted sufficient interest to be seriously road tested. I expect, however, ultimately the goal will remain the same - persuade a process to execute code for you using its higher privileges (capabilities). They may vary to exploit the how in the same way buffer overflows vary depending on the program being targeted, but ultimately the fundamental goal is still the same.

You could always [give it a go](http://www.freebsd.org/). There's also documentation on [the API modifications](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/security/capsicum/documentation.html) I've talked about.

Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with the Capsicum Project, the University of Cambridge, or the FreeBSD Project in any way.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer and the Capsicum stuff is really interesting, something I will have to try out.

Answer (score 1):

Capabilities are different from Permissions, which is what SELinux calls capabilities (doh).

As an example, capabilities can be handed off to other programs, possibly attenuated. This is in contrast to the ACL based models where the access controls are managed separately from the programs.

Think of capabilities as unforgeable references to objects, or possibly a subset of the methods on objects, that can be used at runtime by a program. So if I want someone to have update a report to me, I can pass them a capability (reference to the rw interface of the file), which they can provide to a program acting on their behalf. In turn, they can delegate the update process to someone else, by passing on the capability. I don't have to open up directories to wider access.

This leads to a programming style where the security/trust relationships are considered at design time and come as a fairly natural extension of the usecase: eg if I hand over my camera to someone to use, I am also giving them permission to use it.